# I'm trying to set a new value IF something = 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get a boolean which if equals 1, an image is inserted.

I viewed a tutorial, and made this as a starter to test if it works:

```
AND IF(IF_DRAFT_BEER = '1', 5, 2) = 1
```

I tried to say that *if* **IF_DRAFT_BEER** *=* 1, then set the value to 5, otherwise 2. If that worked, I would try implementing the images.

I printed it this way:

```
$row['IF_DRAFT_BEER']
```

However after inserting the *and if* clause, none of the rows are showing anymore.

Anyone know why this happens? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your line;

```
AND IF(IF_DRAFT_BEER = '1', 5, 2) = 1
```

will basically give the result `5` or `2`, then compare it to `1`. Since neither `5` or `2` is equal to `1`, the comparison will never be true and the query won't return any rows.

I'm not quite sure why you'd have this kind of calculation in a `where` clause though, I suspect you'll want to move your calculation up to the select and actually get it as a result, a'la;

```
SELECT IF(IF_DRAFT_BEER = '1', 5, 2) AS IF_DRAFT_BEER
```

That way it will show up in your result `$row`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll always get a boolean fALSE from that query. Your `IF()` call returns either a `5` or a `2`. You then test that 5 or 2 against a `1`, which will always come out as FALSE.

Drop the last `= 1`:

```
AND IF(IF_DRAFT_BEER = 1, 5, 2)
```

so the 5 and 2 can actually be returned.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that did the trick. I however noticed that the number returned isn't stored, and only the real boolean is printed. How would I go around this?

Comment: Well, there is that `and`... without seeing the whole query, can't say what the problem might be.